# Azure App Gateway Never Picks up Renewed SSL Certs from Key Vault Automatically

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-application-gateway, azure-webapps

I am seeing a peculiar problem whereby my Azure Application Gateway never picks up renewed certs from KV. I have KV as a reference in the listener. I upload new Certs in the KV and also change the Certs in the Custom Domain in the Azure Web App.
But my App Gateway never picks up the new Cert versions automatically. I have to run everytime a fresh Terraform Plan and Terraform Apply and then only the new Certs are detected in App Gateway.
Initially i was loading the Certs directly and that time i thought this was the method to upload new Certs by re running TF Plan and Apply
But now even after connecting my KV to App GW, i still see the same issue.

So adding the KV to my Application Gateway didn't help.

I did the below thing while provisioning the App GW but that is not helping here.
I see this issue now across my two environments, DEV and QA

```
# Get the Application Gateway we want to modify
$appgw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name MyApplicationGateway -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup
# Specify the resource id to the user assigned managed identity - This can be found by going to the properties of the managed identity
Set-AzApplicationGatewayIdentity -ApplicationGateway $appgw -UserAssignedIdentityId "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/MyManagedIdentity"
# Get the secret ID from Key Vault
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "MyKeyVault" -Name "CertificateName"
$secretId = $secret.Id.Replace($secret.Version, "") # Remove the secret version so AppGW will use the latest version in future syncs
# Specify the secret ID from Key Vault 
Add-AzApplicationGatewaySslCertificate -KeyVaultSecretId $secretId -ApplicationGateway $appgw -Name $secret.Name
# Commit the changes to the Application Gateway
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw
```

Comment: How you are checking your current version in application gateway ?